# Add character to iskeyword string, but only at the beginning of a word

Tags: keyword

I wondered if it is possible to add a character to `iskeyword` or similar, but such that it is only allowed at the start of the keyword.

Use case: TeX macros start with `\`

Related question: [Possible to use `!` in `iskeyword`, but only at the end of a word?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12365/possible-to-use-in-iskeyword-but-only-at-the-end-of-a-word)

The issue is, that if I just add `\` to `iskeyword` then `\macroA\macroB` is a single keyword, instead of two keywords.

Comment: I don't think it is possible at all to do that with `iskeyword` (which is probably the reason why the question you linked has no answer)

Comment: @statox yes, I think so, too. But maybe there is someone who's infinitely more intelligent than I am and finds a way :)

Comment: Sure, we have some real Vim Gurus on here maybe someone will have an idea :)

Comment: I doubt this is possible

Comment: @IngoKarkat not sure whether this is really a duplicate, there is an arguable conceptual difference between a leading and a trailing non-word symbol. Though the answer is most likely the same.

Comment: @Skillmon I didn't want to duplicate my answer there. Right now, it's exactly the same issue from the perspective of the Vim design and implementation. And if something like that would be implemented (which I argue would break the design consistency), I'm sure it would be done in an universal way that includes leading and trailing positions.